# editorconfig seems not to be used by visual studio mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I've just added new editoconfig (https://github.com/editorconfig) on solution top level and added as below to have file scope namespacing nevertheless when creating new class namespacing still remains block type. WHat i do wrong?

P.S Is there any possibility to have preview of editor config same way we have on windows system?

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
# IDE0160: Convert to file-scoped namespace
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:silent
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VS Mac doesn't support the `csharp_style_namespace_declarations` property, only the core set of properties (and code style ones):

- `indent_style`
- `indent_size`
- `tab_width`
- `end_of_line`
- `charset`
- `trim_trailing_whitespace`
- `insert_final_newline` root

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/editorconfig?view=vsmac-2022